# How does Chrome's Renderer Code Integrity Protection Work?

Tags: cryptography, google, chrome

I recently heard of Chrome's Renderer Code Integrity Protection, which is apparently supposed to prevent unsigned dlls from being loaded into the chrome.exe process, and figured I'd test what would happen if I tampered with one of Chrome's  default dlls. So, I opened chrome.dll in a hex editor, appended some random data to the end of the file, saved it and verified the "Digital Signatures" tab no longer appeared when I looked through the dll's properties, and opened Chrome. To my surprise, it opened as normal. No crashes, no warnings, nothing. I took a look through the process in Process Explorer and verified the module wasn't signed ("No signature was present in the subject").

To see how far I could push this, I did the same with every dll in Chrome's Application folder, reopened Chrome, checked that every chrome.exe process in process explorer was loading at least one tampered dll, and browsed for a few minutes. Never got a crash, error, or notification that an invalidly-signed dll had been loaded. I verified I was on Chrome version 79 (in which the features was re-enabled after being temporarily disabled in 78), that none of the processes had been launched with the command line option to disable the protection, and that I didn't somehow have the registry setting that disables the protection set.

From my admittedly limited research on the subject, Renderer Code Integrity protection makes use of a Windows 10 feature to require that all modules loaded by any process opting into the feature are signed (I did my testing on an up to date Windows 10 box). It would seem logical that tampering with one of those modules would prevent it from being loaded, causing the application to either crash or produce some kind of warning that a critical dll had been tampered with. However, I haven't been able to find out much else about the feature, with most sites just repeating "it prevents anyone from injecting code into Chrome". Does anyone know the nitty gritty details on how Renderer Code Integrity works and why invalidating the signatures of every dll in Chrome's application folder does nothing to prevent those dlls from being loaded?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/microsoft-defender-atp/exploit-protection-reference#code-integrity-guard explains a bit.